# Double switch case not working properly. Google maps shapes drawing

Tags: google-maps, switch-statement, polygons, popupmenu

I would like to create popup menu which includes: choosing maptypes, choosing shape with citywalls drawn on map.

My problems:

- I have no idea how to clean once picked shape (or switch it to none, method doesnt matter)
- How to make my map not to be loaded again when i change shape.

  ```
  public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
   int id = item.getItemId();

       switch(item.getItemId()){

   case R.id.mediewal:
       shape = new PolygonOptions();
       mMap.addPolygon(shape);
           break;

   case R.id.swedish:
       shape = new PolygonOptions()
      .add(new LatLng(53.426685, 14.565516),
              new LatLng(53.427519, 14.565268),
              ................................
              new LatLng(53.427003, 14.565636))
      .strokeColor(0xB3A60307)
      .fillColor(0xB3670000)
      .strokeWidth(8)
      .geodesic(true);
      mMap.addPolygon(shape);

      shape = new PolygonOptions()
      .add(new LatLng(53.420158, 14.557578),
              new LatLng(53.420285, 14.557832),
              ................................
              new LatLng(53.419972, 14.557818))
      .strokeColor(0xB3A60307)
      .fillColor(0xB3670000)
      .strokeWidth(8)
      .geodesic(true);

       mMap.addPolygon(shape);
       break;

  case R.id.prussian:
       shape = new PolygonOptions();
       mMap.addPolygon(shape);
       break;
   case R.id.none:
       shape = new PolygonOptions();
       mMap.addPolygon(shape);
       break;

   }


   switch(item.getItemId()){
   case R.id.normal_map:
       mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL;
       break;

   case R.id.satellite_map:
       mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE;
       break;

   case R.id.terrain_map:
       mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN;
       break;

   case R.id.hybrid_map:
       mapType = GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID;
       break;
   }


   mMap.setMapType(mapType);
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  ```

Of course Ive put only one test shape here. Currently its working like this: I can pick maptype and pick shape, but no way to clean shape in another way than going out to menu and go maps again.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: related question: [How to delete all the shape after draw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004550/how-to-delete-all-the-shape-after-draw/12006751#12006751)

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I missed "How to delete all the shape after draw" thank You very much!

Comment: Im not using any library, Ive just drawn this shape via google maps api. Topic above probably wont solve my problem ( or I cant transform it properly for my usage), Im still newbie in android.

Comment: I don't know anything about android.

Comment: Well I solved my problem adding

mMap.clear()

Which deletes all lines points and shapes from map. Ive put it in the case 'none'. Map still reloads but all in all I have what I wanted. What's more whis method is not described in Polygon drawing part of API description, but in other chapter.

Topic may be closed, sorry for taking time.

Comment: If you solved the problem, please post it as an answer and [accept it](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: Solution pasted. Im too newbie to accept it ; )

Answer (score 0):

Generaly to avoid loading map over and over again I've moved         `mMap.setMapType(mapType);`under every map type in switch case with mapTypes. Removed ofc this one from `Return` call.

To clen up shapes I call `mMap.clear()` which deletes all shapes and markers from map. Its not perfect solution for everybody, but for my case it's enough.

I think to clen up one shape we should call (with checkbox):

```
 if(item.isChecked()){
         item.setChecked(false);
         polygon2.remove()
         ;}
     else{
         item.setChecked(true);
         polygon2 = mMap.addPolygon(shape2);
         }
         break;
```

Remember to initialize shape e.g. `private Polygon polygon2;`