# How to remove circle,polygon from google map completely

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I draw circles and polygons on Google maps using DrawingManager. I tried to remove a circle/polygon by using the below code.

```
selectedShape.setMap(null);
```

Here `selectedShape` is either circle or polygon.

But it just hides the shape from the view. Internally that shape present in DOM.
For example: I have drawn 2 circles and 2 polygons. Now the total of shapes is 4. If I remove a circle or polygon, the count is still 4. It's not removed from DOM. Just hidden.

I want to completely remove a selected shape out of many shapes.

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: related question: [How to delete all the shape after draw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004550/how-to-delete-all-the-shape-after-draw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Has you can read from the documentation:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/shapes#circle_remove

The `.setMap(null)` does not delete the circle. It simply removes the circle from the map. If instead you wish to delete the circle, you should remove it from the map, and then set the circle itself to `null`.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the prompt reply. How to remove the circle from the map ??

Comment: Set the shape variable to `selectedShape = null` after calling `.setMap(null)`.

Comment: Hi, Still not working.  I just used below code as you said.                                      if (selectedShape) {
    selectedShape.setMap(null);
    selectedShape = null;
 }                                                                                                            Once check this screenshot.[link](http://s19.postimg.org/fia2bhff7/Capture.png) Here i drawn 3 shapes.( Circle , Circle and Polygon.Then i removed 1st circle.And clicked on "Get each Overlay Co-ordinates" button.Still i got 3 as overlay length.Also getting all 3 shapes details.Check in console.