# How to remove drawn circle or polygon from google map using drawing manager - ng2-map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, angular, typescript

How can I remove the drawn circle or polygon using drawing manager from the google map.

**Component:**

```
import {Ng2MapComponent, DrawingManager, Polygon} from 'ng2-map';

export class CreateAlertComponent implements OnInit {
   @ViewChild(Ng2MapComponent) mapObj: Ng2MapComponent;
   @ViewChild(DrawingManager) drawingManager: DrawingManager;

   polygonCompleteFunction(e) {
       console.log(this.mapObj);
   };

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<ng2-map [zoom]="mapOptions.zoom" [minZoom]="mapOptions.minZoom" [center]="mapOptions.center" clickable="false" (click)="mapClick($event)">
                    <drawing-manager *ngIf = "selectedJurisdictions.length > 0" 
                        [drawingMode]="'null'"
                        [drawingControl]="true"
                        [drawingControlOptions]="{
                        position: 2,
                        drawingModes: ['circle', 'polygon']
                        }"
                        [circleOptions]="{
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        strokeColor: 'black',
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        editable: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        zIndex: 1
                        }"
                        [polygonOptions]="{
                        fillColor: 'red',
                        fillOpacity: 0.3,
                        strokeColor: 'black',
                        strokeWeight: 2,
                        editable: true,
                        draggable: true,
                        zIndex: 1
                        }"
                        (polygoncomplete)="polygonCompleteFunction($event)"
                        (circlecomplete)="circleCompleteFunction($event)">
                    </drawing-manager>
</ng2-map>
```

But on polygon complete function or circle complete I am not getting the drawn polygons from the map object

Comment: Refer this link, it'll be definitely helps you.
[click ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006751/5725745)

Comment: Refer this link, it'll be definitely helps you.
[click here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12006751/5725745)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the drawn Polygon or Circle from the `CircleComplete`/`PolygonCompolete` Event's parameter. Or find the target from OverlayComplete event's parameter by event.overlay.
After get the target object, you can keep it somewhere for deleteing them somewhere else.

```
polygonCompleteFunction(e) {
   console.log(e);    // this is the drawn Polygon you are looking for, and same for the circleComplete event
};

overlayComplete(e) {
  console.log(e.overlay);  // here can also find the drawn shape(Polygon/Circle/Polyline/Rectangle)
}
```

While deleting the target Polygon or Circle, delete them by reference the instance kept before.

```
target.setMap(null);
```

Here is the GooleMapApi Documentation about OverlayComplete Events:

> google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'circlecomplete', function(circle) 
>     {
>       var radius = circle.getRadius();
>     });
>
> google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) 
>     {
>       if (event.type == 'circle') {
>         var radius = event.overlay.getRadius();
>       }
>     });

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.cn/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=zh-cn#DrawingManagerOptions) to GoogleMapApi documentation.

Hope it helps. And here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/zU6XDC?p=preview) you can take reference.